# VBA Error 6 Overflow

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am getting run time error 6: Overflow through the below code.

```
n = (.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)   
FillP = Array("D", "E", "F", "H", "I", "J", "M", "O", "P", "AR", "AS", "BE", "BF", "BG", "BH", "BI", "BJ", "BK", "BL", "BQ", "BR", "BS", "BT", "BU", "BV", "BW", "BX", "BY", "CB", "CC", "CD")

'fill blanks with na
For i = 2 To n
    For j = LBound(FillP) To UBound(FillP)
        If Trim(.Range(FillP(j) & i)) = "" Then
            .Range(FillP(j) & i) = "na"
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

I have Excel 2010, I haven't yet declared any of the above variables yet (will do after testing).  Just trying to fill blanks in specific columns with an "na".  Nearly identical code appears earlier in my sub and yet it runs fine.  No idea where i'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Gave that a try, afraid it made no difference.  If it helps n = 2650

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: And what are the values of the variables at that time?

Comment: I can't get the error no matter what I do.  So we need more information.

Comment: You know what, It looks like the cell it's trying to look at to check if it's blank has an error message in it.

Comment: Well that would do it. You will need to add another if/then before the current one to test for the error. `IF Not IsError(.Range(FillP(j) & i)) Then`

Comment: Thanks for your help, you want to make an answer and i'll mark it correct?

Comment: @ScottCraner - A `Variant` will silently promote itself to a `Long` instead of overflowing as an `Integer`.  In fact, it will silently promote itself to a `Double` instead of overflowing as a `Long`.

Comment: @Comintern yeah I noticed that when I tested the OP's code.  I should have deleted the comment then.  Thanks for the comment, I truly like learning from my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

overflow results when you try to assign value to a variable, that exceeds the limitations of the data type. 
I am afraid that you might have declared i, j, or n as Interger.

Also you will not need the dot operator before cells & range.

Answer (score 0):

Where does the error specificaally occur? just from inspection, you do not need the dots before Cells and Range. You would only do that in a with statement